# Close current Java app until another send a signal

Tags: java, jar, process

I want to know if is possible to close the current java app util another has done some task, my code is this:

```
private static void callJar(String jardir) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    // jardir contains the excecution command 
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(jardir);
    synchronized (p) {
        // Here I want to wait for p for a signal but not when p has finished
        // but waitFor() do the second
        p.waitFor();
    }
    // If the other jar is correctly loaded, close this jar
    System.exit(0);
}
```

The string `jardir` contains the excecution command that will start the other process that I will be listening, something like this:

```
jardir = "javaw -jar \\path\\to\\anotherjar.jar"
```

For now, `callJar()` opens this process and then close the current until the process that I started has been terminated. In other words, close A until B has been closed.

But what I want to do is to close A until B send a signal (B will continue to exist).

Is there a way to listen for a signal from the process that I started?

Comment: Have you looked at Java's Concurrency API? https://bharatonjava.wordpress.com/2013/05/30/returning-data-from-java-threads/

Comment: @Chris correct me if I'm wrong, but this only works to communicate many threads inside one jar, no? In my case, I have 2 independly jars running and I want to communicate both

Comment: Could you define "jar?" I don't think what you're describing is what most people would think of when they read "jar." You might mean "process."

Comment: I guess they are two different process as you say. I called "jar" because that's what I opened, but they are running in two different virtual machine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for an answer, I finally found a solution, maybe this will work for someone so here is what I did:

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13153842/3998458) and [this site](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077322/core-java/core-java-sockets-programming-in-java-a-tutorial.html?page=2), I opted to create a communication between two Java apps using the java.net libraries.

In the process A, I have a method that create a server communication and just waits until it receive a message from process B...

```
private static boolean listen2ExternalProcess() {
    ServerSocket server = null;
    Socket serverSocked = null;
    String line;
    BufferedReader inputReader = null;
    try {
        server = new ServerSocket(3333);
        serverSocked = server.accept();
        inputReader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(serverSocked.getInputStream()));

        while (true) {
            line = inputReader.readLine();
            log.info("Client says: " + line);
            if (line.equals("Kill yourself :D")) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        log.error("Don't know about this, " + e);
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Couldn't get IO for the connection, " + e);
        return false;
    } finally {
        try {
            if(serverSocked != null) serverSocked.close();
            if(inputReader != null) inputReader.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            log.error("Couldn't get IO for the connection, " + ex);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

this method will return true if the message has been received, then I can proceed to terminate process A.

In the process B, I have a method that just send a message to a socket when I need it...

```
public static void talk2ExternalProcess() {
    Socket socket = null;
    BufferedWriter outputWriter = null;
    try {
        socket = new Socket("localhost", 3333);
        outputWriter = new BufferedWriter(
            new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        log.error("Don't know about host: localhost, " + e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Couldn't get IO for the connection to localhost, " + e);
    }

    if (socket != null && outputWriter != null) {
        try {
            outputWriter.write("Kill yourself :D");
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            log.error("Trying to connect to unkown host: " + e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("IO Exception: " + e);
        } finally {
            try {
                outputWriter.close();
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                log.error("IO Exception: " + ex);
            }
        }
    } else {
        log.warn("null socket or outputwriter");
    }
}
```

finally, I just change the `callJar` method to something like this:

```
private static void callJar(String jardir) throws IOException {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(jardir);
    if (listen2ExternalProcess()) {
        System.exit(0);
    } else {
        log.warn("Something went wrong...");
    }
}
```

I would like to find an easier answer, but for now, this works for me.